# Geometry package: page formatting is correct for pages with headings e.g. chapter but not for normal ones

Tags: spacing, formatting, header-footer, margins, geometry

I'm new to TeX and I hope you guys can help me out on my problem or give me a hint what I'm doing wrong. I'm using the `geometry` package to format my page the code looks like this:

```
\usepackage[a4paper, left = 3.5cm, right = 1.5cm, top = 2.5cm,, bottom = 2cm, includehead, includefoot]{geometry}
```

The settings above work well and as they should for pages with headings e.g. chapter but not for pages without headings. At the moment a page without heading has a space of 4.5cm between top border and the beginning of text instead of 2.5cm. I guess this problem has to do with `includehead`, but how could I fix this without using `\newgeometry` for every page without a heading or for every page with a heading? If you need any more information, I will provide it as fast to you as possible. Thank you!

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[a4paper, left = 3.5cm, right = 1.5cm, top = 2.5cm,, bottom = 2cm, includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-80pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{This is chapter one}
\newpage
Here is some text...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! There certainly must be something else. Could you post a full, yet minimal, compilable example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: What do you mean with heading? One of your tags is `header-footer` so I would think it could be the header above the text. But that doesn't agree with your description because you say "with headings, e.g. chapter", and chapter pages usually don't have headers. So maybe you mean the Chapter heading. Than it is normal design that there is more white space above the Chapter heading. If you don't want that you have to use another chapter header design.

Comment: Use the `showframe` option to `geometry` to see the margins.

Comment: @Bernard, Thank you both for your answers, I edited my post and added a minimal working example that shows the problem. On the Page with the chapter heading "This is chapter one" the formatting is correct, 2,5 cm from top to the first text. But on the next page without the chapter heading, this does not work and the space is 4,5cm instead of 2.5 and thats what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly normal since you chose the `includeheadfoot` option. So it is the top of the header which is 2.5cm from the top of the sheet. I removed this option and adjusted the second value in `\titlespacing`. Please see if the resulting layout is what you want:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[a4paper, left = 3.5cm, right = 1.5cm, top = 2.5cm,, bottom = 2cm, showframe]{geometry}%includeheadfoot

\usepackage{titlesec, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-13ex}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is chapter one}

Beginning of the first chapter

\newpage
Here is some text...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this snippet, your effort and time, I played bit around with different settings and now everything is set as it should be. Thank you! :)